# In a “using” block is an OracleConnection closed

Tags: c#, try-catch, exit, using, oraclecommand

In a “using” block is an OracleConnection closed if System.Environment.Exit(0) is issued in the catch statement?

Example:

```
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = getOracleConnection();

        using (oracleConnection)
        {

            try
            {

                oracleConnection.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = getApplicantsCmd(oracleConnection);
                OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

                List<Applicant> applicants = new List<Applicant>();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Applicant applicant = new Applicant();
                    applicant.email = (string)rdr["GOREMAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS"];
                    applicants.Add(applicant);                   
                }

                return applicants;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure getting applicant records: " + ex.Message);
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I want execution to stop if an exception is thrown while looking up the records.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You could just have an empty catch, and after the using do `Environment.Exit(0); return null;`, since if it didn't return so far, it surely didn't finish the try block.

Comment: You can also put the using inside the try block, instead of wrapping around it.

Comment: @YoryeNathan which is best practice, putting the using around the try or the try around the using?  I have seen posts doing it both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no call to `oracleConnection`'s `Dispose()` method after the call of `System.Environment.Exit`, even though the variable is wrapped in `using`. If you would like to make sure that the connection is disposed, either put the `using` inside `try`/`catch`, or do not call `System.Environment.Exit` inside `using`. You can still exit if you set a flag, and act upon it after the `using` statement:

```
var mustExit = false;
using (var oracleConnection = getOracleConnection()) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine("Failure getting applicant records: " + ex.Message);    
        mustExit = true;
    }
}
if (mustExit) {
    System.Environment.Exit(0);                
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the connection closes automatically when the app exits anyway though, even without any specific closing or disposing.

Answer (score 5):

The physical connection to the database is not closed. It's just returned to the ADO.NET connection pool for reuse. ADO.NET keeps a pool of connections to avoid opening a physical connection to the database everytime you want to perform a SQL query. You should also wrap your `OracleCommand` and `OracleDataReader` in `using` statements to ensure proper disposal even in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, and is disposed therein too shortly afterwards.

EDIT: unless it is pooled, and as is explained, will be available in the pool again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your question in general is whether the `Dispose` method of object used in an `using` statement will be called if `Environment.Exit` is called withing `using` block.

The answer is no. If you call `Environment.Exit` or `Environment.FailFast`, the process is terminated and finally block (the implicit one, resulting from `using` statement) will not be executed.

On the other hand, if you exit your app by calling `Application.Exit` or `Application.ExitThread` it will be called.